# Problem with recaptcha when testing it with IIS (localhost)

Tags: asp.net, iis, recaptcha

I am using recaptacha in my application and when i am testing it with IIS then it gives me error "operation time out" on recaptcha.validate method however it's work very fine with local port , what should be the reason of that and what should be solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bigb is right, **recaptcha do requires port 80 to communicate with google servers**.

Checkout below threads

- [Operation timed out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598185/operation-timed-out-error)
- [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/recaptcha/OIemf_4hkc0)

You need to **add proxy server setting** for recaptcha in your `web.config` file

Example Taken from [here](http://faq.1and1.com/web_space__access/mssql/11.html)

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy>
<proxy usesystemdefault = "false" bypassonlocal="false"
   proxyaddress="http://ntproxyus.lxa.perfora.net:3128" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your app on different machine, check firewall settings there, recaptcha requires port 80 outbound to communicate with Google servers.